# Connecting water system drain line to sewer

Tags: plumbing, drain, sewer, water-softener, water-filtration

I’m replacing my water filtering and softener system. The only drain we have in the basement is connected to the sewer pipe. The drain line for the old system are T’ed together and connected to the sewer line using an air gap connector. [image: previous setup]

However, the company of the new system said that the drain lines should not be T’ed together. So I need to add 2 more drain lines to the sewer pipe. There are also 3 other drain lines draining into the same place (1 from our AC unit, 2 others from dehumidifiers). So I need a setup that can accommodate 6 drain lines at the same time. I tried the setup in the picture below, and failed miserably… water was splashing out everywhere when the filtering system was regenerating. Please help me figure out what’s the proper way to do this. I’m very confused… especially about the airgap requirement.
[image: my attempt]

Comment: I'm not sure where the Tees are that they complained about, but did they explain _why_ the lines couldn't be Teed together?

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the water splashing issue, I'd suggest either:

1. Push the flexible tubing further down the into the sanitary Tee fitting.
2. Put a cap on the top opening after drilling a hole through for the tube that goes in there. To maintain the air-gap, I'd run a horizontal line from the sanitary Tee to an upturned elbow and insert the tubing through holes into the horizontal line. If the tubes are pushed in far enough that they bend and aim in the "drain" direction, they'll shoot their water that way.